# vb script single line mail merge

Tags: vbscript, mailmerge

I have a peculiar need. I need to be able to read a single line from a csv file, merge the data into a mailmerge document, save the document with a unique name, proceed to the next line, rinse and repeat.

I am complete unaware of how to use/merge a single line of data extracted from a file as a data source for a mail merge.  Can someone give me some insight into what the oDoc.mailmerge... line below should look like?

I know the open and closes in the code below isn't efficient, this is something I through together quickly to get my point across.  I can work the rest out. I just need help with the merge line.

```
DATAFILE = "test.txt"
DOCFILE  = "myDoc.doc"
listFile  = fso.OpenTextFile(DATAFILE).ReadAll
listLines = Split(listFile, vbCrLf)
For Each line In listLines
   WScript.Echo line 
   'My Stuff
   dim objWord, oDoc, wdName
   Set objword = CreateObject("Word.Application")

   wdName = "D:\My Documents\DOCFILE"

   set oDoc = objword.Documents.Open (wdName)
   objword.Visible = True

   oDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource ?line?, , ,True, , , , , , , , , "IDONTKNOWWHATGOESHERE"
   oDoc.MailMerge.Execute

   oDoc.PrintOut
   'redefine savename and execute save here
   oDoc.Close()
   objword.Quit (0)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

OpenDataSource doesn't let you specify individual rows except via SQL. What you would typically do is use a loop to increment (say) iRecord then use

```
obj.MailMerge.DataSource.FirstRecord = iRecord
obj.MailMerge.DataSource.LastRecord = iRecord
```

You could either open the data source every time, but the efficient way would be to open it, then have a loop that sets these two values and does the Execute. Either way, you need to realise that your "oDoc" object will always reference the Mail Merge Main Document, not the document that results from the merge. To access *that* document from VBScript I think you will need objWord.ActiveDocument.

Every other approach seems to me to be more complicated.

However, if you really want to use the OpenDataSource line to control the merge, OpenDataSource (a) needs to work with the disk file, not an in-memory structure such as your listLines array and (b) will need to issue SQL to retrieve a single line (which in turn requires that your data source has a unique key field and (probably) that you know its name and type.

If you have that, then your OpenDataSource line could be something like

```
oDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource "the full path and name of the data file",,,,,,,,,,,, _
"SELECT * FROM X WHERE [fieldname] = " & cstr(theFieldValue)
```

where you get the relevant theFieldValue from the appropriate record in your listLines array. Or, if you know that the field contains a row number, you could generate the number and you might not need your array at all.

If theFieldValue is a string type rather than a numeric type, you'll need something more like:

```
oDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource "the full path and name of the data file",,,,,,,,,,,, _
"SELECT * FROM X WHERE [fieldname] = '" & theFieldValue & "'"
```

"X" is just there to satisfy Word's requirement to have a FROM clause (Word has a very crude internal SQL dialect). OTOH, if Word decides to open the file using its OLE DB provider, you will probably need to pay a bit more attention to the "table name"

Another way you could go would be to use VBScript and the FileSystemObject to create a fresh data file (consisting of the header row + 1 data row) for each data row in the data source. Then mailmerge that entire file.

Comment: Thanks Bibadia, this is exactly what I was looking for.  I appreciate that you explained it so well. (and gave me a couple of options).  I'm mostly a mainframe and Pick Systems guy, so this project has been troublesome for me. Your reply gave me everything I was missing.

Comment: Thanks.  Not sure what you meant by using X as the table name though.  Isn't it just "the full path name of the data file"? e.g. select * from C:\Temp\The_data_file.csv where [fieldname]='theFieldValue'